# How to put application user username on the picture as a result to post on wall?

Tags: php, facebook

I want to make a facebook application that allows a user to share a picture on their wall. The picture will have a blank place to put the username.

I already know how to show the picture, but I can't make their username automatically go inside the picture.

Answer (score 1):

Use an image manipulation library like [GD](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) or [Imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org) to do this.
Open the image, write text onto it (examples are included with both libraries), then save the image and you can upload it to facebook or whatever else you were going to do with it

Comment: No, i mean that i want the username will automatically add inside to my picture that i prepare as a result.

Comment: yes, you'd need to do that via an image manipulation library if you want the username to be visible inside the picture